# How to list threads in the same process?

Tags: windows, multithreading, delphi

I have this code that runs through all threads. I would like to get the threads only from my own process, without having to loop through all the threads running on the system.

```
var
  SnapProcHandle: THandle;
  NextProc      : Boolean;
  TThreadEntry  : TThreadEntry32;
begin
  SnapProcHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
  Result := (SnapProcHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
  if Result then
  try
    TThreadEntry.dwSize := SizeOf(TThreadEntry);
    NextProc := Thread32First(SnapProcHandle, TThreadEntry);
    while NextProc do
    begin
      if TThreadEntry.th32OwnerProcessID = PID then
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Thread ID      '+IntToStr(TThreadEntry.th32ThreadID));
        Memo1.Lines.Add('base priority  '+inttostr(TThreadEntry.tpBasePri));
        Memo1.Lines.Add('delta priority '+inttostr(TThreadEntry.tpBasePri));
      end;
      NextProc := Thread32Next(SnapProcHandle, TThreadEntry);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(SnapProcHandle);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Your English is fine but your code is unreadable. Edit the question, read the help on editing a a format the code. Spend some time doing this. Don't give up after 20s like so many before you.

Comment: dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2055642/800214 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809708/running-threads-count

Comment: It is also difficult to understand the question and how the code relates to it. What do you expect the code to do. What does it do.

Comment: He wants to avoid the loop? seems clear to me...

Comment: Hard to believe that could be the case. The code performs the task correctly but asker wants a different solution that performs the exact same task? Why would anyone want that?

Comment: Anyway, code is from [RRUZ's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2057866/800214)

Comment: I do not understand, the code looks fine readable here.
The aim would be to avoid the loop as @ whosrdaddy mensionou.

Comment: The question has already been edited. Denying you an chance to learn how to do it. Next time you ask the same will happen again. Why do you want to avoid the loop. Your code works. Why not make a feature request to MS to provide a new interface for you to use. Since you don't like the one they gave you that works.

Comment: I see no need to get information out of my context. Maybe podeira be a little more concise that work. But if this is the best way I will use this code yourself.

Comment: RRUZ's answer has the same *typo* and mistake about the delta priority. It's trDeltaPri (typo), and it's not used (mistake). Do not blindly copy code, try to understand before you use.

Comment: I corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with WMI (Windows MIcrosoft Instrumentation).
[Here there are an article](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/procesos-y-threads-glibwmi/) that explain how to retrieve all threads running of one process. The article is in spanish, but you can use authomatic translation o view the code and download samples.

Using WMI you can obtain all information of a process using the class [Win32_Process class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx). 
You can try execute in a console a coomand like this, to obtain information of this class.

> WMIC Process where name="bds.exe" GET Name, description, ProcessId,
>   ThreadCount, Handle

[image]

With this you can obtain information of process.

The second step if "How to retrieve the Threads associated a process". You can do this with the [Win32_Thread class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394494(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you launch a query like this:

> SELECT * FROM WIN32_THREAD WHERE ProcessHandle=10740

You get all the threads of the process 10740 (see ProcessId of the first query).

Regards.

Comment: Good alternative, liked the lib and therefore accept the answer.

Comment: @Mutha - This doesn't avoid retrieving all threads as evident from the sql. Only, it's not  your code which is looping but WMI.

Comment: The provided Spanish article links to a 404. Here's a link to the [translated archived page on Wayback Machine](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://web.archive.org/web/20181207173953/http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/procesos-y-threads-glibwmi/)

Answer (score 2):

You already know how to filter the threads for a specific process, because the code is already doing exactly that:

```
if TThreadEntry.th32OwnerProcessID = PID then
```

All you need is the `PID` for the calling process.  Use [`GetCurrentProcessId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683180.aspx) to get that value.

Unfortunately, `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` does not allow you to restrict the snapshot to a specific process when using `TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD`, the snapshot includes all threads in the system, so you need to filter them on their respective PIDs as you loop through them.

Comment: could not prevent the loop?

Comment: What problem does the loop cause you?

Comment: You can't avoid the loop as the answer explains.

Comment: The cycle does not cause me any trouble, just do not want to access information from outside of my context, I do not see the need for both. So I tried new ideas.